# Documentation on how to install cmcstl2?

Tags: linux, installation, c++

How to install cmcstl2? I am looking for location of instructions for installing [cmcstl2](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2). Normally I install with apt-get but this is not successful for cmcstl2 using a command like:

```
apt-get install cmcstl2
```

Comment: Alternatively, there is Ranges-v3 `sudo apt install librange-v3-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Modification to original and specifics for Ubuntu 17.04 using g++-6 which has `cmake 3.7` rather than the required `3.8`.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2/archive/master.zip
unzip master
cd cmcstl2-master
cat CMakeLists.txt \
    | sed "s/VERSION 3.8/VERSION3.7/" \
    | sed "s/target_compile_features(stl2 INTERFACE cxx_std_17)//" \
    | sed "s/-fconcepts/-fconcepts -std=c++01z/" \
    | cat >CMakeLists.txt
export CXX=`which g++-6`
cmake .
cmake install .
```

Copy these directories (`experimental  meta  stl2`) from: `~/Downloads/cmcstl2-master/include` To: `/usr/include/c++/6`